# Overriding Enterprise Adminhtml block

Tags: magento-enterprise, blocks, magento-1, overrides, reward-points

I've some troubles while trying to override a Enterprise Adminhtml's block.

Here is the Block that I want to override :

> app/code/core/Enterprise/Reward/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Reward/Management/Upgrade.php

Here is the top of my config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myself_Reward>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <depends>
                <Enterprise_Reward/>
            </depends>
        </Myself_Reward>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <enterprise_reward>
                    <rewrite>
                        <customer_edit_tab_reward_management_update>Myself_Reward_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update</customer_edit_tab_reward_management_update>
                    </rewrite>
                </enterprise_reward>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
```

And the file I've created : app/code/local/Myself/Reward/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Reward/Management/Update.php :

```
class Myself_Reward_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update
extends Enterprise_Reward_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update
{
    protected function _prepareForm(){
        DIE("I'll KILL YOU");
    }
}
```

But I didn't see my sweet message...
What do I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've make a mix of all of them and add some things and now It works.

Here is what I did :

My config.xml looks like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myself_Reward>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <depends>
                <Enterprise_Reward/>
            </depends>
        </Myself_Reward>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <myself_reward>
                <class>Myself_Reward_Block</class>
            </myself_reward>
            <enterprise_reward>
                <rewrite>
<adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_reward_management_update>Myself_Reward_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update</adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_reward_management_update>
                </rewrite>
            </enterprise_reward>
        </blocks>
```

My Upload.php :

```
<?php
require_once ('Enterprise/Reward/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Reward/Management/Update.php');
class Myself_Reward_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update
    extends Enterprise_Reward_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update
{
    protected function _prepareForm(){
        DIE("I'll KILL YOU");
    }
}
```

My Upload.php file is inside :

```
app/code/local/Myself/Reward/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Reward/Management/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EE but I reckon your overwrite should be:

```
<blocks>
    <reward>
        <rewrite>
            <customer_edit_tab_reward_management_update>Myself_Reward_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update</customer_edit_tab_reward_management_update>
        </rewrite>
    </reward>
</blocks>
```

Basically the first node under `<blocks>` should match the first node declared under `<blocks>` in `app/code/core/Enterprise/Reward/etc/config.xml`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post, I've tried but It didn't works. :(

Answer (score 0):

This should be your block declaration in config file :

```
<blocks>
    <myself_reward>
        <class>Myself_Reward_Block</class>
    </myself_reward>
    <enterprise_reward>
        <rewrite>
            <adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_reward_management_update>Myself_Reward_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update</adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_reward_management_update>
        </rewrite>
    </enterprise_reward>
</blocks>
```

And, your class name should be `Myself_Reward_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update`, not `Myself_Reward_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, I've tried, but I've : exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Type de bloc non valide : Myself_Reward_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update' in /var/www/app/Mage.php:595

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Myself_Reward>
        <version>0.1.0</version>            
    </Myself_Reward>
</modules>    
<global>
    <blocks>
        <myself_reward>
            <class>Myself_Reward_Block</class>
        </myself_reward>
        <enterprise_reward>
            <rewrite>   
                <adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_reward_management_update>      Myself_Reward_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update</adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_reward_management_update>
            </rewrite>
        </enterprise_reward>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

Make sure to include, Enterprise_Reward_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update in your local update.php file

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but by this way I've got the following error in my var/log/exception.log file : exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Type de bloc non valide (which mean "Invalid Type Block') : Myself_Reward_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reward_Management_Update'